# Why doesn't jQuery's addClass work for me?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, addclass

I've been looking around but can't seem to find a solution to my problem, despite the many many questions there already are about this subject.

I am trying to use jQuery's `addClass` to change the appearance of my dynamically generated navigation bar as well as a static div I have across the website.

However a few weird things are occuring, here is my code:

jQuery:

```
if ($( "body" ).hasClass("page-id-14")) {
    $("#box").addClass("active1");
    alert("why is it not red?");
} else if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-12")) {
    $("#box").addClass("active2");
    alert("Why is it not blue?");
} else if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-10")) {
    alert("Why is it not yellow?");
    $("#box").addClass("active3");
};
```

Relevant HTML

```
<div style="width:50px; height:100px" id="box" div>
```

CSS:

```
 .active1{
    background:red !important;
 }
 .active2{
    background:blue !important;
 }

 .active3{
    background:yellow !important;
 }
```

The first weird problem is that it only recognizes when body has the class "page-id-12" and not the other two occurrences; unfortunately I can't give you a link as I am developing on localhost.

The second and biggest problem is that it does not add the class to the #box div which I am currently testing it on.

Am I drunk or is there actually some weird stuff going on here?

Added my full html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <div class="row"> <!-- Logo row -->
                <div class="col-md-12" id="logo"></div>
            </div>

                <div class="row" id="navbar"> <!-- Navigation row -->
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="m1">

                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
                    </div>
                   <!-- <div class="col-md-4" id="m2">Industrilakering</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="m3">Gulvservice</div> -->
                </div>


                <div class="row"> <!-- Slider row -->
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="slider"></div>
                </div>



                <div class="row"> <!-- Main content row -->
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="sidebar">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'malerservice' ) ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8" id="content">
                        <?php
                            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                                the_content();
                            endwhile;
                            else :
                                _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );
                            endif;
                         ?>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- Main Content -->


        </div> <!-- div col-md-8 -->


        <div class="col-md-2" id"=social">
            <a href="http:/www.faceboook.com"><div id="fbicon"></div></a>
        <a href="http:/www.google.dk"><div id="gplusicon"></div></a>

        </div>





    </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8" id="gallery">
                        <div style="width:50px; height:100px" id="box" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
</div>  <!-- Container fluid -->





<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Change `<div style="width:50px; height:100px" id="box" div>
` to `<div style="width:50px; height:100px" id="box"></div>
`

Comment: I created a fiddle and it works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/797/

Comment: Could you make sure that the DOM is loaded when this code is executed ? Could you add the relevant body HTML in your post ?

Comment: Oh yea... didn't change the outcome though.

Comment: Firstly stop using `!important` statement everywhere...

Comment: I don't intend to keep the !important. I was just so frustrated that nothing was working.

Comment: We can't see what the class of your <body> tag is, and we don't know whether any of the alerts are being triggered - because you haven't actually said those things. And they would be useful to know.

Comment: I did say that the one with page-id-12  is being triggered (alert) while the 2 others aren't. Also the class of my body tag is dynamically added by wordpress.

Comment: This looks a very complex method of doing something with JS/JQ that can simply be handled by CSS.

Comment: How do you handle it with css? I need 3 different colors for active states for my main navigation bar. And i need a div to change color along with the navigation bar buttons.

Comment: SInce you're using WordPress, are you enqueuing the jQuery script correctly? Is it in the footer or the header? Are you using noconflict mode?

Comment: I see someone has already provided the CSS method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer to the most recent comment (how to do it with css)

```
body.page-id-14 #box{
    background-color:red;
}
body.page-id-12 #box{
   background-color:blue;
}

body.page-id-10 #box{
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: So simple! Why didn't i think of that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Exactly...simple and quick.

Answer (score 0):

After minor modififying of HTML Layout to validly close `div` everything works well.
I've updated html from:

```
<div style="width:50px; height:100px" id="box" div>
```

To

```
<div style="width:50px; height:100px" id="box">Some text</div>
```

```js
if ($( "body" ).hasClass( "page-id-14" )) {
  $("#box").addClass("active1");
  alert("why is it not red?");
}else if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-12")){
  $("#box").addClass("active2");
  alert("Why is it not blue?");
}else if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-10")){
  alert("Why is it not yellow?");
  $("#box").addClass("active3");
};
```

```css
.active1{
    background:red !important;
 }
 .active2{
    background:blue !important;
 }

 .active3{
    background:yellow !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class = "page-id-14">
  <div style="width:50px; height:100px" id="box">Some text</div>

   </body>
```

Comment: telling OP that his code work is not useful. Browser can close the div by itself so it should not be part of the issue.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: It looks useful to me. If the OP says something doesn't work, then gives some code, making a runnable version of that code which does work at least proves something

Comment: @ChrisLear then it should be a comment.

Comment: @ChrisLear I agree with you. However i've corrected html automatically(i've missed that edit) even i've  without  pointing on it.

Comment: @Matheno Thanks for your comment, i've "re-did" my answer.